# working with nested array of JSON object in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, angular, typescript

I have data in JOSN format like this.

```
[
{
    "name": "The Godfather",
    "image": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w600_and_h900_bestv2/rPdtLWNsZmAtoZl9PK7S2wE3qiS.jpg" ,
    "reviewRating": {
        "votes": [{
            "rating": 9,
            "votes": 159
        }, {
            "rating": 8,
            "votes": 201
        }, {
            "rating": 7,
            "votes": 49
        }, {
            "rating": 6,
            "votes": 69
        }, {
            "rating": 5,
            "votes": 125
        }],
        "total": 603
    }
}]
```

I tried this inside the HTML file.

```
 <li>
        {{movie.reviewRating}}
</li>
```

Name and Image loading perfectly but when I try to load array of nested objects.This is the output i am getting.

```
[object Object]
```

Comment: How would want them to be loaded? It's not obvious what you want to display.

Comment: I am displaying name and cover image for the movie. I want to display all the votes and rating.

Comment: If you double check your JSON, `movie.reviewRating` is actually an object with the property `votes` (which is an array) maybe you are searching for `{{ movie.reviewRating.votes}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*ngFor` to iterate over `movie` data. And as `reviewRating.votes` is also an array, again you need to iterate over `reviewRating.votes` to display it correctly.

```
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of movie">
      {{ item.name }}<br />
      <img [src]="item.image" />

      <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let vote of item.reviewRating.votes">
            {{ vote.rating }} <br />
            {{ vote.votes }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>        
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) like this

```
<li>
        {{movie.reviewRating | json}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display the values of each rating, you should iterate through them using `ngFor` and, in case you need to show the "total" as well, you can do that as shown below.

```
<li *ngFor="let reviewRating of movie.reviewRating.votes">
   Rating: {{reviewRating.rating}}, votes: {{reviewRating.votes}}
</li>
<li>
   Total: {{movie.reviewRating.total}}
</li>
```

`ngFor` is mandatory because you can't display an array of elements just "as it is", angular just can't guess it alone. ngFor will take care of iterating each item until the collection is finished.